# WSO2 APIM Analytics: getting Error: Error in activating analytics data service: Error in looking up database

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed APIM Analytics 2.5.0 Snapshot and pointed the DB to MS SQL.

Now, I have created two databases as well ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE and ANALYTICS_PROCESS_DATA_STORE.

When starting up the startup script. I am getting below error:

Error in activating analytics data service: Error in looking up database type: Driver:SQLServerDriver:2 returned null for URL:sqlserver://testdb.net;databaseName=ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceComponent}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.commons.exception.AnalyticsException: Error in looking up database type: Driver:SQLServerDriver:2 returned null for URL:sqlserver://testdb.net;databaseName=ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false

I have placed the SQL jars in the lib directory and also in the dropin directory.

Can some one please help me to find where I am doing wrong.

Below is my analytics.datasources.xml file

```
<providers>
    <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    <!--<provider>org.wso2.carbon.datasource.reader.hadoop.HBaseDataSourceReader</provider>-->
    <!--<provider>org.wso2.carbon.datasource.reader.cassandra.CassandraDataSourceReader</provider>-->
</providers>

<datasources>

    <!--<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for analytics record store</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                <username>wso2carbon</username>
                <password>wso2carbon</password>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                <initialSize>0</initialSize>
                <testWhileIdle>true</testWhileIdle>
                <minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>4000</minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>
                <defaultTransactionIsolation>READ_COMMITTED</defaultTransactionIsolation>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>-->


 <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for analytics record store</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>sqlserver://testdb.net;databaseName=ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</url>
                <username>xxx</username>
                <password>xxxx</password>
                <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>200</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
        </configuration>
        </definition>
</datasource>


  <!--<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for analytics record store</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                <username>wso2carbon</username>
                <password>wso2carbon</password>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                <initialSize>0</initialSize>
                <testWhileIdle>true</testWhileIdle>
                <minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>4000</minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>
                <defaultTransactionIsolation>READ_COMMITTED</defaultTransactionIsolation>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>-->

<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for analytics record store</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
       <url>sqlserver://testdb.net;databaseName=ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</url>
        <username>xxx</username>
                <password>xxxx</password>
                <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>200</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
        <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
    </configuration>
        </definition>
</datasource>

    </datasources>

</datasources-configuration>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When commenting the h2 db configuration of **WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB**, you have missed to comment  tag. Can you correct it and check whether it works

Comment: Thanks. But that was my typo. I have corrected it but still its the same

Comment: Could you verify the specified db url for mssql  - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+MSSQL

Comment: I am using the same in other APIM configuration and there it is working fine

Comment: I tried updating the analytics source file but still issue persists.